# How to check if a type is a subtype of another in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, subtype

I've recently found myself in a situation where I wanted to check if a Type is a subtype of another Type this is what I've tried

```
 abstract class Record{}
 class TimeRecord extends Record{}
 
 void test(){
   print(TimeRecord is Record); // return false but why ??
 }
```

Comment: There is no way to do this with `Type` objects.  There generally isn't much you actually can do with `Type` objects.  What are you ultimately trying to do?  There possibly is a better way to accomplish your goal.

Comment: In fact, I've created a generic class which accept type extending a given class and I have a list of that  generic class my problem is that I'm trying to add and element at runtime in that list  and if I don't check that the element is not satisfying that constraint it will raise an exception

Comment: But I'll try it another way, thank you for your advice

Answer (score 8):

The only time it makes sense to check if one type is a subtype of another type is when at least one of the types is a type *variable*. (Otherwise, you can just look at the source and write a constant `true` or `false` into the code).

There is a way to check whether one type is a subtype of another, and it does use the `is` operator, but you need to have an *instance* as the first operand and a type as the second. You can't just create an instance of an unknown type, so we instead rely in Dart's covariant generics:

```dart
bool isSubtype<S, T>() => <S>[] is List<T>;
```

(You can use any generic class, or even create your own, instead of using `List`. All it needs is a way to create the object.)

Then you can write:

```dart
 print(isSubtype<TimeRecord, Record>()); // true!
```

Comment: So if I understand, generics only works for static types  we cannot pass a `runtimeType` to a generic function, can we ?

Comment: Correct. A `Type` object is just an object, it is not a *type* and cannot be used where a type is used (as a type argument or in an `is` or `as` operator). Keep types as *types* as long as possible, and only convert them to `Type` objects if you need to (which should preferably be never, `Type` objects just aren't that great to work with).

Comment: Underrated trick with the lists!

Answer (score 4):

The `is` keyword is used to check if an object instance is an object of type `T`, and not if a type `is` another type:

```
abstract class Record{}
class TimeRecord extends Record{}
 
void test(){
  print(TimeRecord() is Record); // returns true!
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reaching me out but what i f I want a static type checking in reality I don't want to instantiate the class because if it has parameters, and you don't know them in advance it will be impossible to use this approach

Comment: If you want to use is on a type (class) , I guess u'll be able to do it using reflection... (dart:mirrors or reflectable package) Problem is they are not compatible with flutter as far as I know

Answer (score 2):

Just to add up to [@lrn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2156621/lrn) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69114947/9576870).
You could also do something like:

```dart
extension NullableObjectsExtensions<T> on T {
  bool isSubtypeOf<S>() => <T>[] is List<S>;
  bool isSupertypeOf<S>() => <S>[] is List<T>;
}
```

So this way you can test any variable anywhere.