The best way to dispatch dart's runtime type or "can I use dart if-operator for side-effects only"?
I would like to figure out most laconic way to dispatch runtime type and then do something with it.
At the moment I have following fragment:
  if (mmodel is _ChangeReq<T>) {
    mmodel.base.update((list) => list[mmodel.index] = newItem);
  } else if (mmodel is _AddReq<T>) {
    mmodel.growable.updateSuperDuper((list) => list.add(newItem));
  }

(i didn't reduce it so you guys could see the real case)
I don't like the final construction and would prefer to use some switch construction. Alas Dart's switches doesn't support class pattern matching (afaik). So as another alternative we could turn construction above into if-operator based code:
  (mmodel is _ChangeReq<T>)
    ? mmodel.base.update((list) => list[mmodel.index] = newItem) :
  (mmodel is _AddReq<T>)
    ? mmodel.growable.updateSuperDuper((list) => list.add(newItem))
  : throw ArgumentError("Unknown class ${mmodel.runtimeType}");

This one might be a good workaround, except one thing:
We use operator for side-effects only. And we don't use its result. The latter means that at some point it might be optimized out. Or not?
And this is the main question. Is dart's behaviour specified for such a case when we use operators for side effects only and don't use its result? I tried my best to check for specs and was unable to find anything. So I'll be thankful for any hints regarding this matter.

"Alas Dart's switches doesn't support class pattern matching." You can use a variable pattern.  Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/78046886/.

@jamesdlin thanks! That solves problem for this particular case. But what to do if we have dispatch generic parameter. if (subtype<T, int>()) {...} else if (subtype<T, List<int>>()) {...} else {/*etc*/}
NOTE: subtype is a pattern described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69106346/how-to-check-if-a-type-is-a-subtype-of-another-in-dart

I've added an answer to that question showing how to use variable patterns for a case where you have a generic type parameter but no instance of that type.

@jamesdlin, thank you! That makes sense! (you got my upvote) So we covered first part of question pretty well. Now it remains to figure out side-effects-only operators behaviour, is here any guarantee that it will be always executed or not..

Yes, it's guaranteed to be executed, so long as the code reaches that point because the condition is true. That's just the way Dart works. You can use conditional expressions in all sorts of ways, like this: someNullableVariable ?? someMethod();. Normally you'd use the value returned by ??, but you don't have to. You don't have to worry about it being "optimized out." It is always executed for the very reason that it might have side effects.

@Clavum, thank you! Is here any mentioning of this statement in dart.dev or Dart Language specification?

Indirectly...yes. Section 17.24 in the language spec is about conditional expressions. It says a conditional expression "evaluates one of two expressions based on a boolean condition." The key there being "one of two." At least one of the two expressions will be evaluated (meaning the code is run) and there is no situation in which the code will be skipped from being evaluated (if the condition is met).

@jamesdlin, Clavum (sorry only one user can be mentioned with 'at')
Guys, would you like to convert your comments into answers or should I arrange it into a single answer leaving credits to both of you?

This is why you should ask multiple questions separately. =P The "The best way to dispatch dart's runtime type" aspect is basically a duplicate of How to check if a type is a subtype of another in dart.  The question about side-effects is separate.

@jamesdlin Type dispatching is somewhat different from single check. The latter usually simpler: you can use either is (for variables) or List<T> / SubtypeOf<T> workaround (for generic parameters, hope dart team will fix it one day). No need to use patterns in this case. And the question you mentioned was rather about single checks.

Oops, I meant How to pattern match the runtimeType of a class?.  I got mixed up because you ended up asking 3 different questions...

I don't really mind who posts the answer. However, I did answer what you called your "main question" and James has enough rep already lol. You could answer it yourself, but that seems unnecessary, idk. I'll go ahead and post my answer, feel free to do with it what you want.

I wouldn't suggest using a conditional operator in this case, because if you run Dart formatting, it will look rather strange:
(mmodel is _ChangeReq<T>)
      ? mmodel.base.update((list) => list[mmodel.index] = newItem)
      : (mmodel is _AddReq<T>)
          ? mmodel.growable.updateSuperDuper((list) => list.add(newItem))
          : throw ArgumentError("Unknown class ${mmodel.runtimeType}");

Adding more types/conditions in the future means the spacing will continue to increase and you'll have less space (assuming you care about using the formatter, of course).
Anyway, as for your "main question" about whether the code could be optimized out...
It's guaranteed to be executed, so long as the code reaches that point because the condition is true. That's just the way Dart works. You can use conditional expressions in any way you see fit, even if it's atypical, like this:
void main(Object? someNullableVariable) {
  someNullableVariable ?? someMethod();
}

Normally you'd use the value returned by ??, but you don't have to. You don't have to worry about it being "optimized out." It is always executed for the very reason that it might have side effects.
To back my claims up with a source, Section 17.24 in the Dart language spec is about conditional expressions. It says a conditional expression "evaluates one of two expressions based on a boolean condition." The key there being "one of two." At least one of the two expressions will be evaluated (meaning the code is run) and there is no situation in which the code will be skipped from being evaluated (if the condition is met).
It's a similar story with other expressions as well, like ??. The spec gives step by step explanations on how they are run, and never say anything about the usage of the return value having an influence on the execution (or the execution being conditional at all).
